# Crie uma condição com um número aleatório inteiro - ternary operator

Tags: javascript, condição, números-aleatórios, inteiros

Estou a aprender por mim Javascript e a executar alguns exercícios. Tenho este que não consigo executar:

"Generate a random integer number between 0 and 99 and assign it to the luck variable.

Write a condition that should check if Mr. Pink's luck is greater than 90. If so, the conditional statement should assign 'Mr. Purple'  to alias. Otherwise, it should assign 'Mr. Pink'.

Print the alias value to the console."

Eles deram- me um exemplo:

```
[CODE=javascript]var speed;

var whatNow = speed < 80 ? 'BOOOM!' : 'Keep driving';

console.log(whatNow); // if speed is lower than 80 bus explodes; if not, you better keep driving[/CODE]
```

Deram me já as variáveis luck e alias, agora tenho de completar o resto.Inseri o código abaixo, mas devolve a mensagem >>>>Code is incorrect
Remember to generate a random number between 0 and 99. That number needs to be an integer.

```
[CODE=var luck = Math.random()*99;
var alias = luck > 90 ? 'Mr. Purple' : 'Mr. Pink';
console.log(Math.ceil(luck));
console.log(alias);[/CODE]
```

Já tentei de várias formas como encontro online, mas existe sempre problema com o Mathrandom, e já criei linhas com este método.

Alguém consegue ajudar por favor?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer gerar um número inteiro aleatório, então você irá precisar arredondar o resultado de `Math.random`.

Para isso você pode utilizar o `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil` ou `Math.round`.

No seu código você até tentou utilizar `Math.ceil`, mas lembre-se que ele irá arredondar qualquer número maior que 0 e menor ou igual a 1, em *1*, o que significa que o seu código nunca irá gerar o número *0*.

Se você preferir utilizar `Math.floor`, então multiplique o resultado por *100*. O resultado de `Math.random` nunca é igual a 1, então o resultado de `Math.floor() * 100` sempre será arredondado para no máximo *99*.

O restante está correto... ao menos no quesito de lógica. As strings deveriam ser *Mr. Pink* e *Mr. Purple* (com ponto), e não é necessário imprimir o valor de `luck`

```js
var luck = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var alias = luck > 90 ? 'Mr. Purple' : 'Mr. Pink';
console.log(alias);
```

Comment: Olá, Muito obrigada pela ajuda, resultou, de fato já tinha tentado com o Math.floor, mas algum passo estava errado, e também tinha uma linha a mais do rpint.